# Using jOWL Sparql_Dl to return ObjectProperties of a specific class

Tags: javascript, sparql, owl

I am using [jOWL](http://jowl.ontologyonline.org/SPARQL-DL.html) to help visualize an ontology. I have returned the classes and subclasses in separate dropdowns.

I want the user to be able to click on an option to reveal a form showing the ObjectProperties associated with with the selected class.

So far I have been able to return all ObjectProperties of the ontology using:

```
jOWL.SPARQL_DL("ObjectProperty(?x)").execute({
    onComplete : function(results) {
              // Putting results into form
 };
```

And have tried to limit to specific class (in this case RedWine) using

```
jOWL.SPARQL_DL("SubObjectPropertyOf(?x, RedWine)").execute({
    onComplete : function(results) {
             // Putting results into form
 };
```

Any ideas how how this could be done would be much appreciated. I have not seen many people asking questions about jOWL, maybe it is not the best plugin to use so if there are any alternative suggested that would also be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that this [library](http://ontologyonline.org/) (jOWL) is maintained anymore (the [last blog post](http://ontologyonline.blogspot.co.uk/) dating from 2009) therefore it will be difficult to find some help on it.

I suggest that you have a look at the [OWL API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/), you will find lots of support on it using either the mailing list or asking your questions there. This library is actively maintained and reliable.

You can also have a look at [Jena](http://jena.apache.org/) which is an excellent solution too. If your ontology fits the OWL2 EL profile, you could also use [Brain](http://loopasam.github.io/Brain/).

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is interested I think this is returning the specific properties for the selected class, however it is difficult be completely sure as it seems most classes share the same Object Properties.

```
jOWL.SPARQL_DL("PropertyValue("+selected+", ?p, ?x)").execute({
    onComplete : function(results) {

   //then separate arrays of properties and their values in other function

};
```